# ng-options filter doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I need to filter ng-options to display only the result that i want.
This is my html

```
<select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="main.orderNameForUpdate"
    ng-options="singleOrdersProduct.name for singleOrdersProduct in main.singleOrdersProductOptions | filter:{ category.name : 'Pizza Favorites' }">
</select>
```

This is my data structure

[image]

But i got some errors

So anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Some errors?? wat do you mean by that

Comment: @RanjithS 
Object]nexpected%C%expecting%%5B%A%D&p2=52&p3=main.singleOrdersProductOptions%%7C%filter%A%B%category.name%%3A%main.addFoodFilter%%7D&p4=.name%%3A%main.addFoodFilter%%7D

This one

Comment: @Arg0n still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="main.orderNameForUpdate"
    ng-options="singleOrdersProduct.name for singleOrdersProduct in main.singleOrdersProductOptions | filter:{ category: { name : 'Pizza Favorites' }}">
</select>
```